# Problem finding a vulnerability in memcpy

Tags: vulnerability, buffer-overflow

I have some troubles to find the buffer overflow vulnerability in this piece of code, it is with memcpy but I am confused on the result it gives :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i;
        char username[128] = {0};
        char msg[2048] = {0};
         // the user types the command he wants
        i = read(STDIN_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg)-1);
        memcpy( username, msg+2, i-2);

        return 0;
}
```

Does someone understand ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Compare the sizes of the target (username) and the origin (msg). Does all of msg fit into username?

Comment: Hey thanks for you quick answer yes I agree but  the +2 in memcpy put only the third character of msg in username, that is why I don't understandt, I have tried with a long enough payload and still no segfault

Comment: You asked for a buffer overflow. Not every buffer overflow results in a segfault and not every segfault is caused by a buffer overflow. And a vulnerability can also be if  data end up in the wrong place.

Comment: Another hint: what happens if i is 1 or 0?

Comment: So it must be a null pointer dereference, it may be stupid to ask but how can I know if I correctly exploited this ?

Comment: Looks like you did not look at or did not understand the last hint. I get a segmentation fault using this hint with both values :)

Comment: Ok, when I print nothing, and I think this was what you said about 0  ;) I have a segmentation fault, the pb is that it is a shortened part of a server code, and to perform memcpy, I have to at least type a command that  starts by 'u'

Comment: And what about 1 which could fit the condition of starting with 'u'? Also, have you asked yourself why you get the segfault?

Comment: Well with 1 it doesn't do any segfault or maybe i got it wrong by what you meant by 1. 
Well I think that if I print nothing the msg + 2 won't point to anything so that would cause the segfault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in the code:
The first one is that the target `username` is shorter than the source `msg` and that thus a long `msg` can cause a overflow of `username`. But given the code this results only in flowing into `msg`, i.e. no crash.

More interesting is the following part:

```
    int i;
    ...
    i = read(STDIN_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg)-1);
    memcpy( username, msg+2, i-2);
```

If `int i` is 0 or 1 this will cause `i-2` as the last argument of memcpy to be negative (i.e. -2 or -1). Since the type of the last argument is `size_t` which is usually unsigned this negative signed value will be treated as a huge unsigned value. Thus in effect the code gets on platforms with 64 bit `size_t` when `i` is 1:

```
    memcpy(username, msg+2, 0xffffffffffffffff)
```

This way the copy will quickly reach memory areas which don't belong to the process so that a segmentation fault occurs.

The needed values for `i` can be reached by either just closing the input (`i=0`) or giving exactly one byte of input (`i=1`, i.e. no additional new lines or similar) with for example

```
    echo -n "u" | ./crashme
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) when I do it with echo, it works, because the read must take the \n as a character.

Comment: And what is more, you were right at the beginning, and it is pretty obvious that we can write arbitrary data into the stack just with a payload longer than 128 even if it doesn't cause a segfault